# Filter bounty questions by tag

Tags: discussion, tags, bounties, filtering

I could not find a way to filter bounty questions by tag (e.g., Excel)

Is that possible at all?

**EDIT** ("research" inspired by answers)

Answers below explained why I was not seeing a *featured* tab for tag *excel*.

The way to arrive at an explicit message stating that there are no featured questions with a given tag is by first clicking on the *featured* tab, and then searching for the tag in the top right search field (*excel* in this case).

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there are any active bounty questions then you can click the tag [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) and you can find it under **featured** tab.

Currently there is no bounty question under excel tag, that is why you can't see `featured` tab. For [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) tag it would look like:

[image]

Comment: I obviously spent too long on my circles! :)

Answer (score 3):

In my experience the easiest way is to go to the tag, and look at the featured tab.  If the featured tab exists then there is a question with a bounty, if no tab then there are no bounty questions.

Example, tab with bounty:

> [image]

No bounty:

> [image]

Comment: The second image corresponds to the present situation, that is why I was not seeing the tab.

Comment: @sancho.s That is why I included both for the comparison. I'm not active in the excel tag so I don't know how often you would get a bounty it in.

Comment: Note that due to caching it can take a couple of minutes for the tab to appear.

Answer (score 0):

(Added for completion) The other two answers posted explained why I was not seeing a *featured* tab for tag *excel*.

The way to arrive at an explicit message stating that there are no featured questions with a given tag is by first clicking on the *featured* tab, and then searching for the tag in the top right search field (*excel* in this case).

[image]